# Coinbase API setup in php with curl

Tags: php, api, curl, coinbase-api

Can someone show me a basic curl setup? I'm reading about 50 ways to do it, but its all looks messy. Bittrex uses this is it similar for coinbase?

```
$apikey='xxx';
$apisecret='xxx';
$nonce=time();
$uri='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/getopenorders?';
$uri += 'apikey='.$apikey.'&nonce='.$nonce;
$sign=hash_hmac('sha512',$uri,$apisecret);
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
$execResult = curl_exec($ch);
$obj = json_decode($execResult);
```

Comment: The code in your post looks right. Is there something specifically that didn't work?

Comment: there is a library available on github which should help take away the pain https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-php

Comment: currently that code isn't broke. I managed to turn that into a function and make multiple calls. I've read threw the coinbase-php but that is chopped up so much and makes other resource calls. I don't understand it, and don't need more than half that stuff. I just need a balance, buy, and sell call with out all the bells and whistles.

Comment: not to mention that wants us to use composer and I don't know what that is, or even how to begin to use it. I've tried in the past couple of weeks, but its beyond me. I had more success with the python version than I did with the php version. But I don't know enough about python.